# Reactive Form Validity with Initial Disabled Control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I currently have a Reactive Form which is built in the following way:

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: this.formBuilder.control({value: null, disabled: true}, [emailValidator, Validators.required]),
    username: this.formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required])
});
```

I have a CSS class that I am adding to an element on my DOM that is dependent on whether or not the form is valid (both fields have values):

```
[class.disabled]="!formGroup.valid"
```

The only problem is, when the `username` control is empty, the CSS class is applied, but as soon as I enter a value, the CSS class is removed even though the second control, `email` still has no value (the value shown is the placeholder).

[image: ReactiveForm]

[image: ReactiveForm]

I'm wondering if this is caused by the `value: null` in the form state object. Even though the value is `null`, the control still has a value meaning that when the `username` is entered, the form enters the `valid` state.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead checking form is valid you can simply check whether control is valid or not

try this

```
[class.disabled]="!formGroup.controls['email'].valid"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
email: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.email])
FormControl this.formBuilder.control
```